# Download large files with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, download

My small project for internal use is something like "file share portal like sharerapid", it will be use about 100 people. I have problem with downloading large files. Small files (< 200 MB) are downloading fast, but largest files block my server for 2-5 minutes. Maybe problem is with RAM, I have 2 GB ram. My code to download file:

```
def custom_send(userfile)
    file = userfile.attachment.file.url.to_s.split("?").slice(0..-2).join("?")
    send_file "#{Rails.root.to_s}/public#{file}" , filename: userfile.name, x_sendfile: true
end
```

I don't know where is problem, in develop mode on my localhost machine is OK, but problem is on public virtual server(ubuntu 12).

Answer (score 0):

what web server are you using?  the most likely cause is that the request is blocking further requests in a single-threaded environment.

the best solution to your problem would be to host the files on amazon s3 and link to them there.  if the files must remain local, you could try something more like this:

http://www.therailsway.com/2009/2/22/file-downloads-done-right/

Comment: apache with passenger.I need store data localy(security reasons). I try it before I create this question, but not working, but I think I don't activate module. I installed it with apt-get, restart apache. Where do I add "XSendFileAllowAbove on"? I added it to http.conf(don't work) and myapp_apache_virtualhost_conf (don't work).